# Error while Launching activity en el emulador Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo corriendo el emulador nativo que lleva Android Studio 2.1.2, me encuentro que solo una vez me carga la aplicación dentro del emulador, y las siguientes veces que le doy para compilar me sale el error:

> Error while Launching activity

Comment: Estoy probado la solución de http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity,

Comment: Intente hacer un _Clean & Build_, quizá sirva de algo.

Comment: El final lo solucioné con desactivar instant run y realizar xlwan and build, pero como mi PC es amd, los tiempos de espera me han desesperado y me he pillado un dispositivo con android 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer es un problema con la versión de AS cuando el AVD intenta usar el mismo .apk con la opción "Instant Run".

Podría ser una solución deshabilitar la opción para este caso:

`File` > `Settings` > `Instant Run` .  deselecciona "Enable Instant Run"